# How to use comparison and ' if not' in python?

Tags: python

In one piece of my program I doubt if i use the comparison correctly. i want to make sure that ( u0 <= u < u0+step ) before do something.

```
if not (u0 <= u) and (u < u0+step):
    u0 = u0+ step # change the condition until it is satisfied
else:
    do something. # condition is satisfied
```

Comment: Python magic: u0 <= u < (u0 + step)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can do:

```
if not (u0 <= u <= u0+step):
    u0 = u0+ step # change the condition until it is satisfied
else:
    do sth. # condition is satisfied
```

Using a loop:

```
while not (u0 <= u <= u0+step):
   u0 = u0+ step # change the condition until it is satisfied
do sth. # condition is satisfied
```

Answer (score 10):

[Operator precedence in python](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary)
You can see that `not X` has higher precedence than `and`. Which means that the `not`  only apply to the first part `(u0 <= u)`.
Write:

```
if not (u0 <= u and u < u0+step):
```

or even

```
if not (u0 <= u < u0+step):
```

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case the clearest solution is the S.Lott [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153260/how-to-use-comparison-and-if-not-in-python/4153749#4153749)

But in some complex logical conditions I would prefer use some boolean algebra to get a clear solution.

Using De Morgan's law ¬(A^B) = ¬Av¬B

```
not (u0 <= u and u < u0+step)
(not u0 <= u) or (not u < u0+step)
u0 > u or u >= u0+step
```

then

```
if u0 > u or u >= u0+step:
    pass
```

... in this case the «clear» solution is not more clear :P

Comment: Interesting advice generally, but as You said, it does not help clarity in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Why think?  If `not` confuses you, switch your if and else clauses around to avoid the negation.

> i want to make sure that ( u0 <= u < u0+step ) before do sth.

Just write that.

```
if u0 <= u < u0+step:
    "do sth" # What language is "sth"?  No vowels.  An odd-looking word.
else:
    u0 = u0+ step
```

Why overthink  it?

If you need an empty `if` -- and can't work out the logic -- use `pass`.

```
 if some-condition-that's-too-complex-for-me-to-invert:
     pass
 else: 
     do real work here
```

Comment: "sth" is "some thing?"  In what language?

Comment: I think I saw this abbreviation in some dictionaries. Anyhow I'm not native English speaker, excuse my English mistakes!

Comment: maybe the inversion of "some-condition-that's-too-complex-for-me-to-invert" is equal to; "not (some-condition-that's-too-complex-for-me-to-invert)" works?

Comment: I totally agree with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways. In case of doubt, you can always just try it. If it does not work, you can add extra braces to make sure, like that:

```
if not ((u0 <= u) and (u < u0+step)):
```